# Host verification failed error when running git clone inside dockerfile on AWS EC2 instance as host and a private git repository

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, docker, dockerfile

I am using AWS ec2 instance as private git repository. This instance is also used for running Dockerfile and docker file tries to checkout code from this private repository. My basic setup is done as per https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command/ option 2. However, when i am running my docker build command:

$ sudo docker build -t "spring-petclinic" .

The build script stops at line:

RUN /root/.ssh/git.sh -i /root/.ssh/.pem clone ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/usr/local/git-repos/spring-petclinic.git

and gets following error:

***"Cloning into 'spring-petclinic'... Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."***

I have search through google for this type of error, on similar kind of setup, but unable to search for.

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is that it's connecting for the first time to an unknown host and SSH plays it safe by default. If you were running the command interactively, you'd get prompted to add the key to your known_hosts file.

You can either add the host key to the `known_hosts` file (better) or set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no` in the ssh config (worse).

Comment: How do you add the host key to the ```known_hosts``` file?

Comment: Easy way: connect from your host machine to the target once, then copy `~/.ssh/known_hosts` into the docker image (by `ADD`ing it in the Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, I ended up doing
```RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts```
which did the same thing you described, automatically in the dockerfile